# Random Number Generation-full period

Tags: random-number-generation

How can i demonstrate that a LCG has full period? Is there a way to demonstrate it or do I just need to check the parameters(a, c, m)?

Comment: There's a whole subsection on this topic in Knuth's TAOCP volume 2 chapter 3.